# MySQL server not started

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mysql-5.5

I try to start my MySQL server with another defaults file:

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld --defaults-file=/tmp/test-mysql-37693.cnf
```

and then I get an error and I don't understand whats going wrong:

```
[Warning] Using unique option prefix key_buffer instead of key_buffer_size is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
[ERROR] An old style --language value with language specific part detected: /usr/share/mysql/english/
[ERROR] Use --lc-messages-dir without language specific part instead.
[Warning] Can't create test file /dev/shm/test-mysql-37693/eiscalle-PC.lower-test
[Warning] Can't create test file /dev/shm/test-mysql-37693/eiscalle-PC.lower-test
[Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
[Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Table 'mysql.plugin' doesn't exist
[ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'create'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

My config file:

```
[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
# user      = mysql
pid-file    = /tmp/test-mysql-37693.pid
socket      = /tmp/test-mysqld-37693.sock
port        = 37693
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /dev/shm/test-mysql-37693
tmpdir      = /tmp
language    = /usr/share/mysql/english
skip-external-locking
plugin_dir      = /tmp/test-mysql-37693-plugins

bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 400
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M
```

MySQL server's version is 5.5
So, how can I start my MySQL server?

UPDATE:

my default config file:

```
# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
#general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id      = 1
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Comment: Try `sudo service mysqld start` ...

Comment: yeah, it works but with this file its not started

Comment: Can you post your default conf file pls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Ubuntu uses some security software called AppArmor that specifies the areas of your filesystem applications are allowed to access. Unless you modify the AppArmor profile for MySQL, you'll never be able to restart MySQL with the new datadir location."
(from http://article.my-addr.com/?show=linux_ubuntu_change_datadir-move_mysql_database_to_other_path)

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly means,

try this :

> killall -9 mysqld

**UPDATE:**

> shell> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld"

***Refer this link: [for official site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/windows-start-command-line.html)***

## Ubuntu version :

```
ubuntu@P3-SD1:~$ sudo service mysql stop
[sudo] password for ubuntu: 
mysql stop/waiting

ubuntu@P3-SD1:~$ sudo service mysql start
mysql start/running, process 6957

ubuntu@P3-SD1:~$ sudo service mysql restart
mysql stop/waiting
mysql start/running, process 7164
```

Comment: sry, I have ubuntu 14.04 on my desktop

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't know about **Ubuntu** seriously telling today only install Ubuntu with windows7... And i ill download form official site Ubuntu 14.04 But it occur some error,.. I'm trying again and again but no use,...  if don't mint pls give me your **mail_id** just for instruction only... at least give me your fake id... pls help me... my official_id: **rgkrish183@gmail.com**

Comment: Are you used to install **cd** or **dvd** or **pendrive** or **virtual box** or **windows installer**

Comment: check my answer for **`Ubuntu.`**